# Using same array to store data repeatly

Tags: c

I'm reading data from a file word by word and trying to store in same buffer with space between every word. But words are coming out without space. Please tell me what is wrong?
output coming   aniljaiswalvikaskumarnikhilkumarindia  but i want space between each word.

```
int main()
{
    char buff[200];
    int l=0;
    FILE *fp;
    fd = NULL;``
    fp = fopen("header.c","r");
    memset(buff,0,200);
    while(1)
    {
        fscanf(fp,"%s",buff+l);
        l=strlen(buff);
        printf("Word of string = %s\n",buff);
        printf("Length of string = %d\n",l);
        if(feof(fp))
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: add space character explicitly to your `buff` after each `scanf`

Comment: Well, you never add any spaces. Where did you expect them to come from?

Comment: i think use fetc and put each character to buff ... there will not be problem with that

Comment: this output is coming i want space between them..

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the fact that you are exposed to buffer overflow, you can simply add the space:

```
fscanf(fp,"%s",buff+l);
l=strlen(buff);
buff[l] = ' ';
l++;
```

Answer (score 0):

The full working code :

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<string.h>

     int main()
        {
            char buff[200];
            FILE *fp;
            char c;
            int len=0;
            int i=0;
            fp = fopen("header.c","r");
            memset(buff,0,200);
            while((c=fgetc(fp))!=EOF)
            {
                len++;
                buff[i++]=c;
                if(c==' ' || c=='\n')
                {
                printf("Word of string = %s\n",buff);
                printf("Length of string = %d\n",len);
                }
            }

            fclose(fp);
            return 0;
        }
```

Comment: no problem..... but sometimes scanf creates problem so it's the safest way to read a file

Comment: Already ... answered.. check the 2nd answer given by Binyamin